# Unsure of how to handle this linker error.. (not really ROS related)

Tags: ros, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From https://github.com/PR2/linux_networking/blob/master/wpa_supplicant_node/CMakeLists.txt as the CMakeLists used to compile this program. Was wondering if anyone has experience with these sorts of errors. I understand the undefined reference is a missing link between a library.. my major concern would be: how to convert this https://github.com/PR2/linux_networking/blob/master/wpa_supplicant_node/CMakeLists.txt to the Hydro one presented prior. Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated.

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 10
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 10
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 19
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to` main'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `RosApi::init2()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN6RosApi5init2Ev[RosApi::init2()]+0x119): undefined reference to` eloop_register_read_sock'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `RosApi::uninit()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN6RosApi6uninitEv[RosApi::uninit()]+0x29c): undefined reference to` eloop_unregister_read_sock'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::ros_interface(ros::NodeHandle const&, wpa_supplicant*)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interfaceC2ERKN3ros10NodeHandleEP14wpa_supplicant[_ZN13ros_interfaceC5ERKN3ros10NodeHandleEP14wpa_supplicant]+0xc52): undefined reference to` eloop_register_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::setCountryCode(char const*)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface14setCountryCodeEPKc[ros_interface::setCountryCode(char const*)]+0x1b8): undefined reference to` eloop_register_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::scanCompleted(wpa_scan_results*)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface13scanCompletedEP16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::scanCompleted(wpa_scan_results*)]+0x142): undefined reference to` eloop_cancel_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::assocFailed(unsigned char const*, char const*)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface11assocFailedEPKhPKc[ros_interface::assocFailed(unsigned char const*, char const*)]+0x148): undefined reference to` eloop_cancel_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::assocSucceeded()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface14assocSucceededEv[ros_interface::assocSucceeded()]+0x162): undefined reference to` eloop_cancel_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::publishNetworkList()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface18publishNetworkListEv[ros_interface::publishNetworkList()]+0x7a): undefined reference to` wpa_config_get_all'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::setDriverCountry()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface16setDriverCountryEv[ros_interface::setDriverCountry()]+0x1c7): undefined reference to` eloop_register_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::delayedPublishFrequencyList(void*, void*)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface27delayedPublishFrequencyListEPvS0_[ros_interface::delayedPublishFrequencyList(void*, void*)]+0x48): undefined reference to` eloop_register_timeout'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::stopActiveAssociation()': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface21stopActiveAssociationEv[ros_interface::stopActiveAssociation()]+0x21c): undefined reference to` wpa_supplicant_disassociate'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::startActiveAssociation(actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<wpa_supplicant_node::AssociateAction_<std::allocator<void> > >&)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface22startActiveAssociationERN9actionlib16ServerGoalHandleIN19wpa_supplicant_node16AssociateAction_ISaIvEEEEE[ros_interface::startActiveAssociation(actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<wpa_supplicant_node::AssociateAction_<std::allocator<void> > >&)]+0x2fd): undefined reference to` wpa_bss_get'
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface22startActiveAssociationERN9actionlib16ServerGoalHandleIN19wpa_supplicant_node16AssociateAction_ISaIvEEEEE[ros_interface::startActiveAssociation(actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<wpa_supplicant_node::AssociateAction*std::allocator<void > >&)]+0x4ab): undefined reference to `eloop_register_timeout' wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface22startActiveAssociationERN9actionlib16ServerGoalHandleIN19wpa_supplicant_node16AssociateAction_ISaIvEEEEE[ros_interface::startActiveAssociation(actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<wpa_supplicant_node::AssociateAction_<std::allocator<void> > >&)]+0x4ce): undefined reference to` wpa_supplicant_associate'
CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function `ros_interface::fillRosBss(wpa_supplicant_node::Bss_<std::allocator<void> >&, wpa_bss&)': wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface10fillRosBssERN19wpa_supplicant_node4Bss_ISaIvEEER7wpa_bss[ros_interface::fillRosBss(wpa_supplicant_node::Bss_<std::allocator<void> >&, wpa_bss&)]+0x137): undefined reference to` wpa_bss_get_vendor_ie'
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface10fillRosBssERN19wpa_supplicant_node4Bss_ISaIvEEER7wpa_bss[ros_interface::fillRosBss(wpa_supplicant_node::Bss*std::allocator<void >&, wpa_bss&)]+0x169): undefined reference to `wpa_parse_wpa_ie' wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface10fillRosBssERN19wpa_supplicant_node4Bss_ISaIvEEER7wpa_bss[ros_interface::fillRosBss(wpa_supplicant_node::Bss_<std::allocator<void> >&, wpa_bss&)]+0x1ab): undefined reference to` wpa_bss_get_ie'
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface10fillRosBssERN19wpa_supplicant_node4Bss_ISaIvEEER7wpa_bss[ros_interface::fillRosBss(wpa_supplicant_node::Bss*std::allocator<void >&, wpa_bss&)]+0x1dd): undefined reference to `wpa_parse_wpa_ie' CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function` ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult_std::allocator<void >&, wpa_scan_results&)':
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface11fillRosRespERN19wpa_supplicant_node11ScanResult_ISaIvEEER16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult*std::allocator<void >&, wpa_scan_results&)]+0x9e): undefined reference to `wpa_scan_get_ie' wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface11fillRosRespERN19wpa_supplicant_node11ScanResult_ISaIvEEER16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult_<std::allocator<void> >&, wpa_scan_results&)]+0x28c): undefined reference to` wpa_scan_get_vendor_ie'
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface11fillRosRespERN19wpa_supplicant_node11ScanResult_ISaIvEEER16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult*std::allocator<void >&, wpa_scan_results&)]+0x2cd): undefined reference to `wpa_parse_wpa_ie' wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface11fillRosRespERN19wpa_supplicant_node11ScanResult_ISaIvEEER16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult_<std::allocator<void> >&, wpa_scan_results&)]+0x31e): undefined reference to` wpa_scan_get_ie'
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text.*ZN13ros_interface11fillRosRespERN19wpa_supplicant_node11ScanResult_ISaIvEEER16wpa_scan_results[ros_interface::fillRosResp(wpa_supplicant_node::ScanResult*std::allocator<void >&, wpa_scan_results&)]+0x35f): undefined reference to `wpa_parse_wpa_ie' CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/src/nodes/wpa_supplicant_node.cpp.o: In function` ros_interface::lockedScanTryActivate()':
wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface21lockedScanTryActivateEv[ros_interface::lockedScanTryActivate()]+0x4fe): undefined reference to `eloop_register_timeout' wpa_supplicant_node.cpp:(.text._ZN13ros_interface21lockedScanTryActivateEv[ros_interface::lockedScanTryActivate()]+0x51a): undefined reference to` wpa_supplicant_trigger_scan'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/marco/pr2_hydro_packages/devel/lib/wpa_supplicant_node/wpa_supplicant_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [linux_networking/wpa_supplicant_node/CMakeFiles/wpa_supplicant_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194081/unsure-of-how-to-handle-this-linker-error..-(not-really-ros-related)/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to call `pkg_check_modules(WPA_SUPPLICANT REQUIRED libwpa_supplicant)` in order to set up the cmake variables for the wpa_supplicant include directories and libraries.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-10-02**:
Hm, I did that and it didn't work out.  checking for module 'libwpa_supplicant'
--   package 'libwpa_supplicant' not found.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-02**:
The old package was buiding wpa_supplicant from source. You'll need to replicate that in cmake: https://github.com/PR2/linux_networking/blob/master/wpa_supplicant_node/Makefile

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-02**:
Or just ditch the whole package. It isn't used anywhere on the PR2.